# Every time I turn off or reboot from ubuntu, the boot are lost

Tags: boot, uefi

That .. Every time I turn off or reboot from ubuntu, the boot are lost ...

No Grub menu, nothing ... just this message:

**No boot device available**

**SATA 0: Installed**

**SATA 1: Installed**

**SATA 2: None**

**SATA 3: None**

More information:

- Ubuntu 12.10 (with all the updates)
- UEFI boot without security (dual boot with windows 8) (My Dell XPS 8500 had windows 8  EOM and therefore UEFI boot :'( )
- Only using windows I have no trouble
- The  "Boot-Repair" don't work (URL: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1554023/)
- In any LiveCD , I can see and manage my HD

To recover the grub I have done is to use a recovery disk windows without making any kind of handle on the machine, just put my disc, I say start my machine ("Continue to windows 8") and went directly to grub but if I happen to get linux sometime I lose the boot

Somebody can help me?
If you need more information, please tell me

Thank you

Comment: Please indicate the URL that appears after using Boot-Repair's Recommended Repair.

Comment: of course @LovinBuntu : [link]http://paste.ubuntu.com/1554023/

Comment: Update Boot-Repair ('boot-sav' and 'boot-repair' packages) before any use.  Also look at the 1st paragraph of https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Nop, After doing that I had to reinstall everything and I lost access to the system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait until Ubuntu fully supports UEFI ...

After install and reinstall all my OS, ubuntu is doing the same all the times (lost the boot system)...

I found that Ubuntu does not support the "Intel® Rapid Storage Technology", this affect directly the GPT ...

currently only recommend wait out the ubuntu 13.04 (with a rescovery USB close)